# How to make speech bubble appear on hover in text

Tags: html, css

I want to appear a speech box which contains text information or image on hover. When a mouse moved hovered text then the speech box appears just like Wikipedia.
I had tried by creating some code but the problem is that the box not aligned with the hovered text and I can't able to use a speech box in a paragraph when I add a speech box in a text that text gets make a separate para. I hope you will understand what I want to know, If not try me help out to create an information box just like Wikipedia.

The code which I have written:--

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.speech {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 8px solid #666;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
  display: none;
}

.speech:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 38px;
  top: 100px;
  border: 15px solid;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent #fff;
}

.speech:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 30px;
  top: 100px;
  border: 25px solid;
  border-color: #666 transparent transparent #666;
}

.myDIV:hover+.speech {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>Display an Element on Hover</h2>


<div class="myDIV">Hover over me.</div>
<div class="speech">I am shown when someone hovers over the div above.</div>
```

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/rd6hy9gz/

Comment: the same I had made I want that I  a para I can put hover on any text without getting Divison that is text should be in the same para.

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your div's inside another relative positioned div.
2. Speech div should be the first child of the relative parent div, and positioned absolute.
3. Then you can adjust the speech div by styling as such: "top: xxpx; left:xxpx".
4. Change css to show .speech when parent div is hovered.

You should have the relative position parent div so your speech bubble can be adjusted depending on the parent's position.

Here's a example below:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <div style='position:absolute' class="speech">I am shown when someone hovers over the div above.</div>
    <div class="myDIV">Hover over me.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't able to understand please make changes code I provide. Please